# this.onChange is not a function when using ControlValueAccessor in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular

I am using ControlValueAccessor to pass data between a child component and a parent which works as expected but when I initialize the component I get always the error

> ERROR TypeError: this.onChange is not a function

After that the code works as expected and the values are past from the Child componenet to parent correctly. The section of my code that threows the error is **this.onChange(formData.selectField)** after I subscribe to the change event. Sio not sure what causes this error and how to get rid of it. I have a feeling that the onChange function is not registered when i try to call it or something like that extend

```
import {
  Component,  forwardRef,  Input,  OnInit,  AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {  AbstractControl,  ControlValueAccessor,  FormControl,  FormGroup,  NG_VALIDATORS,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,  Validators,} from '@angular/forms';
import { Button } from '../models/button.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-toggle',
  templateUrl: './button-toggle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-toggle.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ButtonToggleComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ButtonToggleComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ButtonToggleComponent
  implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, AfterViewInit
{
  @Input() guid: string;
  @Input() isRequired = false;
  @Input() multiSelect = true;

  private _disabled = false;

  value;
  selectField;
  form: FormGroup;
  onChange: Function;
  onTouched: Function;
  validateFn: Function;
  @Input() trackOptions: Button[];

  constructor() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('After View Init');
    this.getInitialChecked();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectField = new FormControl(this.value, []);
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      selectField: this.selectField,
    });
    if (this.isRequired) {
      this.form.get('selectField').setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.form.get('selectField').updateValueAndValidity();
      this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    }

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((formData) => {
      this.onChange(formData.selectField);
      this.value = formData.selectField;
    });
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.value = value;
    this.form.get('selectField').setValue(this.value);
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    //return this.validateFn(c);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  onValChange(e: number, b: boolean) {
    if (b === true) {
        this.setCheckedButton(e);
   
    } else {
      this.setUncheckedButton(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`registerOnChange` method is called after `writeValue`. In write value you're updating your form.

While it's okay to set value for `FormControl` within `writeValue` method but it's useless to listen to `valueChanges` at that point because value comes from consumer and we don't need to notify about it back.

So, try not to fire `valueChanges` event within `writeValue` by using `emitEvent` option:

```
this.form.get('selectField').setValue(this.value, { emitEvent: false });
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error, like i said before even so it worked before i don't like errors hanging around.